# jQuery automatic html divs

Tags: jquery, html, sections

I need to add sections to a content page with jQuery.

I need to do it this way so my client can use a text editor without worrying about html.

So this:

```
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
```

Would become

```
<div class="section">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

So far I have this jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
var i = 0;

var headers = $('#post-2618 h2');

headers.each(function(){
    i++;

    if(i == 1){
        $(this).before('<div class="section">');
    }else{
        $(this).before('</div><div class="section">');
    }
});

$('#post-2618').after('</div>');

});
```

But that makes the code look like this

```
<div class="section"></div>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div class="section"></div>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
```

I think the browser corrects the html before the end of the script.

Is there an easy way around this?

Thank you for your help!

Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.before and .after  adds dom elements not text.

what you should do is the folowing:

```
    $("h2").each(function() {
      //create section dom element
      section = $("<div class='section' />");

      //find all p tags until next h2  and wrap all in the section dom element
      $(this).nextUntil("h2").wrapAll(section);
      //find newly appended .section element and grab the h2
      $(this).prependTo($(this).next(".section"));   
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/81ncLnnL/1/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but this is not working, it creates a div after every h2 like this:

<h2></h2>
<div class="section"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>

Comment: yes it does. but what do you want to do? 
do you want wrap something in the section div?

Comment: I would like to wrap the h2 and following paragraphes in a section div, and this for every h2 in the page

Comment: So it would look like this <div class="section"><h2></h2><p></p></div>